# EXC_BAD_ACCESS at removeFromSuperview - using ARC

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller

In one of my ViewControllers (ViewController A), I have the following code:

```
AlertViewController *aViewController = [[AlertViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AlertViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.view addSubview:[aViewController view]];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:[aViewController view]];
```

And in AlertViewController, I have a button and when the user clicks on it, I have:

```
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
```

Whenever I click the button, the result is EXC_BAD_ACCESS.
I'm unable to figure out the problem. My project is using ARC and ViewController A is part of a navigation controller stack if that info helps.

Comment: You can't remove `self.view` from its superview. What view are you trying to hide?

Comment: @Rickay I'm trying to hide the whole view in AlertViewController's xib

Comment: If you want to hide the view, then just use `self.view.hidden = YES`, but honestly, if hiding the view controller's view shows something beneath it, you aren't using view controllers properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the UIView doesn't own its UIViewController. In the first block of code you held the UIView around by adding it to a subview, but let the UIViewController go away. The UIView from a UIViewController is special, you can't let this happen.

Make sure the UIViewController that created the UIView lives as long as the view does.

Comment: Normally you'd do it by adding your viewController as a child to the owning VC. `[self addChildViewController:aViewController];`

Comment: I made aViewController as an ivar and thats how I could retain it. It works now.